# Avoid applying alpha aesthetic to geom_text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following `ggplot2` chart.  I don't want transparency on the value labels.

[image: ggplot2 chart]

**Code:**

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = reorder(org, -as.numeric(level)), y = obsAvg, fill = level, alpha = round)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(.5, .75, 1), guide = FALSE) + 
  labs(title = "Average Observation Score by Round", y = "", x = "", fill = "Group") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(obsAvg,1)), vjust = -.5, size = 4, fontface="bold", position = position_dodge(width = .9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,4), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(
  org = rep(c("Mammals", "Cats", "Tigers", "Lions", "Cheetahs"), 3),
  level = rep(c("Animals", "Family", rep("Species", 3)), 3),
  group = rep("Cats",15),
  round = rep(c("Round1", "Round2", "Round3"),5),
  obsAvg = runif(15, 1, 4)
)
```

I have tried moving the `alpha = round` to be an aesthetic of `geom_bar()` but then I lose the dodge of the labels:

[image: without dodge]

How can I replicate the top chart but not apply the transparency aesthetic to my labels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would move the `aes(alpha=)` to `geom_bar` and then add an `aes(group=)` to `geom_text` to recover the dodging.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = reorder(org, -as.numeric(level)), y = obsAvg, fill = level)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(alpha=round), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(.5, .75, 1), guide = FALSE) + 
  labs(title = "Average Observation Score by Round", y = "", x = "", fill = "Group") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(obsAvg,1), group=round), vjust = -.5, size = 4, fontface="bold", position = position_dodge(width = .9)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,4), expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

That's a pretty plot.

Comment: The other way would be to explicitly unmap it via `alpha = NULL` in `geom_text`.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, thanks.  As did the comment from joran, adding the `group = round` and `alpha = NULL` both to the `geom_text` and leaving the rest as is.